# Prove that the image of a line lies on a plane

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, 3d, plane-geometry

Problem I have:
There's a point `E` that is the center of projection. There is a plane `s` such that it does not contain `E`. Let `L` be a line such that it does no go through `E`, and does not lie in `S`. Prove that the image of `L` is in `S`.
I have tried to solve this using properties of similar triangles and also some vector stuff but I haven't gotten any closer to the proof.
Any Ideas on how I can prove this?
--Edit--
Regarding what I've tried, we know that a line lies on a plane if two points on the line also lie on the plane.
To do this, I assumed `E` is at `(0,0,0)` and that `L`, and `S` intersect the X-Axis at `(x1, 0, 0)` and `(x, 0, 0)` respectively.
I also assumed that a line that goes through the origin intersects the `S` and `L` at `(x, y, z)` and `(x1, y1, z1)` respectively.
This gives me two similar triangles (that I thought will help with the proof) and points (to make equations for the lines) but none of that led to a proof and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: What sort of projection? It looks like you’re talking about a central projection along lines through $E$ but that not at all clear. If so, what are you projecting onto? If it’s onto the plane $S$, then there’s nothing to prove: the image of any point other than $E$ lies on $S$ (if you’re working In projective space, that is; if not, the plane through $E$ parallel to $S$ has no image under the projection). If it’s onto something else, then there’s a simple argument that the image of the line does _not_ lie on $S$.

Comment: @amd it's a perspective projection onto the plane S, which is a screen.

Comment: In that case, as I’ve said, there’s not really anything to prove. By definition, the image of every point other than $E$ lies on $S$. If $L$ happens to lie on the principal plane, its image will be entirely at infinity. Are you sure that what you’ve written in this question is actually what you’re meant to prove? Perhaps you’re also meant to show that the image is a line? (Also trivial, since any projective transformation is a colineation.)